# runtime error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, runtime-error

My program is **searching in list of tuples**  I wrote it as the following

```
import List
data BookInfo = Book Int String [String]
  deriving(Show)

enter :: Int->String->[String]->BookInfo
enter id name subject=Book id name subject
bookId   (Book id _     _  ) = id

index :: BookInfo -> Int
index (Book id name subject) =  bookId  (Book id name subject) 

arrayentering ::BookInfo->[BookInfo]->[BookInfo]
arrayentering (Book id name subject) [] =[(Book id name subject)]
arrayentering (Book  _  "     " ["    "]) [] =[]
arrayentering (Book id name subject) [(Book it namr suject)]=                         
              (Book id name subject):[(Book it name suject)]
toList::[BookInfo]->[Int]
toList [(Book id name subject) ]=   map index [ (Book id name subject)]

bubbleSort::(Ord t) => [t]->[t]
bubbleSort[x,y,z,xs]=
                if x<y then x : [y,z,xs]
                       else y : [x,z,xs]

superBubble::(Ord t) => [[t]]->[[t]]
superBubble a=map bubbleSort a

combining::[BookInfo]->[[Int]]
combining [(Book id name subject)]=superBubble [toList [(Book id name subject)]]
```

and clean it from any syntax error but after i try to enter to a list of tuple to `combining()` it gve me runtime error say

`Exception:Not Exhaustive pattern in function Main.combining`

What does this mean?

**Please, give me only instructions. If possible, I would like to fix it by my self.**

Comment: +1 for not wanting the answer given to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern in the function definition

```
combining [(Book id name subject)]=superBubble [toList [(Book id name subject)]]
```

matches only lists with exactly one element. You have a similar problem in `bubbleSort`, where

```
bubbleSort[x,y,z,xs]=
```

matches only lists with exactly four elements and elsewhere.

I haven't figured out how you intend it to work, perhaps using a variable pattern (that matches all arguments)

```
combining books = superBubble (toList books)
```

would be appropriate?

---

I suspect

```
arrayentering ::BookInfo->[BookInfo]->[BookInfo]
arrayentering (Book id name subject) [] =[(Book id name subject)]
arrayentering (Book  _  "     " ["    "]) [] =[]
arrayentering (Book id name subject) [(Book it namr suject)]=                         
              (Book id name subject):[(Book it name suject)]
```

should really be

```
arrayentering book bookList
    | empty book = bookList
    | otherwise  = book : bookList
      where
        empty (Book _ name subject) = all isSpace name && all (all isSpace) subject
```

(`empty` may be wrong).

And `toList` should probably be just `map index`.

Comment: sorry but what the import file of `isSpace`

Comment: You have to `import Data.Char` for that. But you should probably better not construct invalid `Book`s in the first place.