# Haskell syntax error

Tags: haskell, if-statement, compiler-errors

I add the **last function and importance function**  - `bSearch()` and link it with `combining()`   as following

```
       combining::[BookInfo]->[[Int]]

       combining books=superBubble [(map index books)] 
        bSearch [xs] key s
                  if length[xs] <> s then return 9999
                  else
                  if
                    key=m then elemIndex m [xs]
                  else
                    if key<m then bsearch (splitAt (x:xs) o) key o 
                   else bsearch (splitAt ms (o+2) ) key n  
                  o<-s/2-1
                  n<-length ms
        finalBsearch::(Ord)=> [a]->a->a->Int
        finalBsearch ms key s= bsearch  (combining [ms]) key s
```

but it give me an error `Syntax error in input (unexpected keyword "if")` at line 5 
thank u for help
= for more details about the full code see [runtime error in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511536/runtime-error-in-haskell)

**But please give me instructions only not full solution**

Comment: It looks like you are having some trouble with formatting and indenting your code. Have you considered trying to use an editor that can help you indent your code properly, like Emacs? (Emacs may be tricky to learn, but I don't know which other editors handle Haskell well.)

Comment: [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) handles Haskell indentation well, and has a shallower learning curve than Emacs. It's not completely up to date on all the latest syntax extensions though, so if that bothers you it might be better to use vim or emacs.

Comment: thank u for help i will download it now

Comment: You know, variables that contain lists don't need to have brackets around them to remind the compiler or anything. The compiler knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix, enclose the whole `if`-`then`-`else` expression in parentheses: `(`-`)`. But this will fix only this error message. Your code contains many more errors. I can't tell what you expect this code to do.

Instead of using cascading `if`-`then`-`else`s, you may find it clearer to use guards.

n.b. You do not have an *exception*; you have a *compilation error*.

Comment: thank u for help , what do you mean by guards?

Comment: There are explanations of guards in [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#deftypes.guard), and no doubt there are other tutorials.

Comment: thank u for help i get a good informations from it